MySQL - Getting wrong result trying to get random result from big table
I've a very big table (around 19.000.000 records), and I want to select 10 rows randomly.
I found this solution:
select *
from my_table as one
where one.id >=
    (
        select FLOOR(rand() * (select max(two.id) from my_table as two)) as currid
    )
limit 10

That should work.
But, if I execute only the random part I get very often big ids (5, 6, 12, 15 milions, for example), but the complete query return always low ids (2k, 5k, 8k, ...).
If I replace the where condition with a static value (e.g. 12 milion) i get the correct result.
Can't understand how it is possible.
Regards
EDIT
Maybe I explained myself wrong.
Executing query more and more times, i got ALWAYS results with "random" id from 1 to 10k.
Statistically, on 19 million records, I've 0.05% of probability to get an id under 10k. Multiplied x10 I've 0.5% chances to get one of ten (my LIMIT 10) ids under 10k, heavily incongruous compared to 100% of times I'm getting ids < 10k.
Instead, if I execute subquery alone, I get ids that seems to be like equally probably distribuited.

I would guess that it is re-evaluating the sub query repeatedly for each row in my_table so you get lots of opportunities for it to generate a low number. Rather than it just evaluating it once and using a "static value"

"If I replace the where condition with a static value ..." ?? (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/ixNfflJF , which seems not to be the desired result!)

LIMIT 10 without an ORDER BY is always going to buggy. Without it, the order the rows are tested is arbitrary.  Either order by a random number, and pick the first 10, or order deterministically and filter (in the where clause) by a random number.  (It's probably currently evaluating the rows in id order, and picking the first 10 that satisfy the where clause.)

The reason why your query is not working is because the sub-query (select FLOOR(rand() * (select max(two.id) from my_table as two)) as currid) is executed multiple times.
To get the first 10 random number do this:
SELECT
  id,
  FLOOR(rand() * (select max(two.id) from my_table as two)) as currid
FROM my_table
ORDER BY currid
LIMIT 10;

see: DBFIDDLE
NOTE: rounding/flooring the results of RAND() is not even needed.
EDIT:
This might be quicker, because the random-id is only determined 10 times (when doing LIMIT 10). Note however that then id numbers should not have gaps (every id between 1 and 10 should exists, otherwise you would miss results in the ens)
SELECT id
FROM my_table
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 
     FLOOR(rand() * (select max(two.id) from my_table as two)) as currid
  FROM my_table WHERE id between 1 and 20 
  ) x on x.currid = my_table.id
LIMIT 10

see: DBFIDDLE

Wow! That's works as expected (example img) could do explain me why? "currid" returns always low numbers, how it is possible?

currid is not needed. A simple ORDER BY RAND() is better

@yotheguitou ORDER BY RAND() is very slowly on large tables (impracticable in my case)

@Luca4k4: added something which should make things faster even when querying 19M records.

@Luuk That's nice but it doesn't work if some id are missing

I updated the edit with: updated the EDIT with ... 20 and LIMIT 10 (now 50% percent of the id can be missed )

You have 19 million data.
Now, you expected the result within 10 million.
So, the probability to get 10 million within 19 million, 10/19 = 0.52.
Try with this query:
select '19 M' as total_record,
    concat(FLOOR((rand()*19)), ' M') as result_with_in19M;

Check how many times you get record within 10M. It should be almost 50% approximately.
This is not an issue. This is your misconception.
Think logically.

There are lots of logic to get random value.
For example, you want to get lower value.
Now we know, if we multiply two decimal values(x, y) which are less than 1 then, there multiplication result (x*y) is near to zero and both number is greater than multiplication result.
So, according to this logic you may modify you query like:
select '19 M' as total_record,
    concat(FLOOR((rand()*rand()*19)), ' M') as low_result_with_in19M;

This will give you approximate low value than previous query.
I hope this will correct your  misconception.
Thank you!!!!!!

There's definitely a language barrier here, but it seems like you completely misunderstood what OP is asking.
